# In trepl or luajit, how can I find the source code of a library I'm using?

Tags: lua, torch

Let's say I'm working with a lua library I installed using luarocks, and I want to see the definition of a function from that library. In ipython in could use

> > ??function_name

to see the definition in the terminal, in matlab I could use

> > which function_name

then use my editor to look at the path returned by which. How could I do something similar to find the function definition for a lua library?

Comment: May be `Easy help with: ? funcname` (see [link](https://github.com/torch/trepl))

Comment: Unfortunately the ? help doesn't show the path, at least in my version of LuaJIT, 2.1.0-alpha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 'plain' Lua/JIT, you can say [`debug.getinfo`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-debug.getinfo)`( func )` and will get a table containing (among others) the fields `short_src`, `source` and `linedefined`.

For Lua functions, `short_src` will be the filename or `stdin` if it was defined in the REPL. (`source` has a slightly different format, filenames are prefixed with an `@`, a `=` prefix is used for C functions or stuff defined interactively, and for `load`ed functions, it will be the actual string that was loaded.)

You can pack that up in a function like

```
function sourceof( f )
    local info = debug.getinfo( f, "S" )
    return info.short_src, info.linedefined
end
```

or maybe even start an editor and point it there, e.g. (for vim)

```
function viewsource( f )
    -- get info & check it's actually from a file
    local info = debug.getinfo( f, "S" )
    local src, line = info.source, info.linedefined
    if src == "=[C]"   then  return nil, "Is a C function."  end
    local path = src:match "^@(.*)$"
    if path then
        -- start vim (or an other editor if you adapt the format string)
        return os.execute( ("vim -fR %q +%d"):format( path, line ) )
    end
    return nil, "Was defined at run time."
end
```

And just for fun, here's yet another version that returns the code if it can find it somewhere. (This will also work for functions that have been generated at run time, e.g. by calling `load`, and where no source file exists. You could also work in the other direction by dumping the `load`ed snippet into a temp file and opening that…)

```
-- helper to extract the source block defining the function
local function funclines( str, line1, lineN, filename )
    -- if linedefined / lastlinedefined are 0, this is the main chunk's function
    if line1 == 0 and lineN == 0 then
        filename = filename and filename.." (main chunk)"
                             or "(chunk defined at runtime)"
        return "-- "..filename.."\n"..str
    end
    -- add line info to file name or use placeholder
    filename = filename and filename..":"..line1 or "(defined at runtime)"
    -- get the source block
    local phase, skip, grab = 1, line1-1, lineN-(line1-1)
    local ostart, oend -- these will be the start/end offsets
    if skip == 0 then  phase, ostart = 2, 0  end -- starts at first line
    for pos in str:gmatch "\n()" do
        if phase == 1 then -- find offset of linedefined
            skip = skip - 1 ; if skip == 0 then  ostart, phase = pos, 2  end 
        else -- phase == 2, find offset of lastlinedefined+1
            grab = grab - 1 ; if grab == 0 then  oend = pos-2 ; break  end
        end
    end
    return "-- "..filename.."\n"..str:sub( ostart, oend )
end

function dumpsource( f )
    -- get info & line numbers
    local info = debug.getinfo( f, "S" )
    local src, line, lastline = info.source, info.linedefined, info.lastlinedefined
    -- can't do anything for a C function
    if src == "=[C]" then  return nil, "Is a C function."  end
    if src == "=stdin" then  return nil, "Was defined interactively."  end
    -- for files, fetch the definition
    local path = src:match "^@(.*)$"
    if path then
        local f = io.open( path )
        local code = f:read '*a' 
        f:close( )
        return funclines( code, line, lastline, path )
    end
    -- otherwise `load`ed, so `source`/`src` _is_ the source
    return funclines( src, line, lastline )
end
```

A closing remark:  If you paste code into a Lua/JIT REPL, `local`s disappear between definitions, because every line (or minimal complete group of lines) is its own chunk.  The common fix (that you probably know) is to wrap everything into a block as `do`*paste*`end`, but an alternative is to `load[[`*paste*`]]()` (possibly with more `=`s like `[===[` and `]===]`.)  If you paste this way, the above `dumpsource` (or any other function using `debug.getinfo`) will then be able to get the source of the function(s). This also means that if you defined a nice function but it's gone from the history and the scroll buffer, you can recover it in this way (*if* you defined it by `load`ing and not directly feeding the interpreter). Saving the source in a file will then also be possible without copy-pasting and not require editing out the `>>` prompts.

Comment: Awesome answer! Those functions would be nice additions to TREPL.

Comment: In order to get the view_source function to work, I needed to add the line "src = str.sub(src, 2, -1) " after the third line of the function.

Comment: @user1546029 Hmm, interesting… the table returned by `debug.getinfo` contains two fields named `source` and `short_src`, where `source` is prefixed by `@` if it's a file, but `short_src` isn't. So this _should_ work (and it does, for me, on Linux+Mac OS in Lua 5.2+5.3 and LuaJIT, also on Solaris in Lua 5.1). What's the char you need to remove? And what OS are you on? (The OS really _shouldn't_ matter but I have no idea why this should break…)

Comment: I'm using Springdale Linux, a Red Hat distro. short_src didn't work as a path because it was preceded by three dots. source was a path from the root preceded by an @, which is what I removed. Sorry I forgot to mention that I switched from using short_src to source in my last comment.

Comment: @user1546029 Ah, good to know that `short_src` breaks on some systems, thanks! Edited to use `source` now (and added yet another variant ^^).