# Is there any way to get source code from imported Lua module?

Tags: lua

is it possible to reverse the code completely from imported LUA module?

For example we have

> mymath.lua

as a module

```
local mymath =  {}

local a = 1

function mymath.add(a,b)
   print(a+b)
end

function mymath.sub(a,b)
   print(a-b)
end

function mymath.mul(a,b)
   print(a*b)
end

function mymath.div(a,b)
   print(a/b)
end

return mymath
```

and we have

> testmodule.lua

that import mymath module

```
mymathmodule = require("mymath")

for key,value in pairs(mymathmodule) do
    print(key, value)
end
```

I managed to print out function declaration but I cant get like parameter or what is inside those function. In Python, we could reverse imported module, is there any way to do this in LUA?

Comment: On the surface, it seems like this question would be answered by determining how "require" finds "mymath.lua", for then you could just read the file. How is your question more involved than that? Please [edit] to identify the problem better.

Answer (score 3):

You can only do this with regular Lua so long as your program has access to the uncompiled source. [debug.getinfo(f)](https://www.lua.org/pil/23.1.html) retrieves a table including the source file name and line numbers where a function was defined. The following is inspired by [inspect.getsource(object)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#module-inspect) in Python:

```
local function inspectSource(f)
  local info = debug.getinfo(f, "S")
  if info.source and string.sub(info.source, 1, 1) == "@" then 
    local source = string.sub(info.source, 2) 
    local i = 0
    for line in io.lines(source) do
      i = i + 1
      if i > info.lastlinedefined then
        break
      end
      if i >= info.linedefined then
        print(line)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Usage:

```
mymathmodule = require("mymath")
inspectSource(mymathmodule.mul)

-- Output:
--          function mymath.mul(a,b)
--             print(a*b)
--          end
```

There's much to improve, but its a start! As-is, the above assumes the module source is in the working directory.

Comment: A few years ago, I wrote a more feature-complete version as an [answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29872347/805875) – that may be worth a look.

Answer (score 0):

Lua doesn't have a built-in mechanism for taking compiled Lua code and regenerating the original Lua text from it. In many cases, information is simply lost; parameter names and other local variables just don't exist in text form after compilation.

There are various Lua decompilers out there, but even they can't guarantee the ability to get the string back.

That having been said, you can always replace the Lua script module loader with your own. The loader reads the string from the file and compiles it, so all your loader would have to do is store that string somewhere so that you could access it later. Even so, it's not exactly a trivial process.